# Different transparency for in-call menu

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, cydia

I'm using ios7.1 and I was wondering if there's a way to change the transparency of the in-call menu?
When I use the dialer's keypad I have about 30% transparency (I can see the background but it's mostly covered in white), but when I'm in the middle of a call, the background is about 70-80% transparent, so if I have a light wallpaper, I can't see the menu or the numbers.

I'm looking for a tweak that will enable me to manually change the transparency or tweak it from iFile.
Second option: set a dark wallpaper only for in-call menu (is it possible?)

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

No, this is impossible using official iOS builds. This has never been possible in the past, and probably never will be a user-editable option on iOS. If your iPhone is jail-broken (which is implied by mentioning iFile) there might be a way to do this, but I'm not familiar with that.